# Any shame in copying from a grant proposal body to create an abstract?

Tags: funding, writing, writing-style, abstract

I have to write an abstract for a grant proposal's cover page.

### Is there any shame in strategically copying/pasting *entire sentences* from the body of the grant proposal and arranging them coherently to form the abstract?

On one hand, it feels funny to have (e.g.) the opening sentence be the same, and if the reviewers notice it, it might look unprofessional. On the other hand, if it's a well-written sentence, why should it matter if it were reused?

Comment: [Looks in the mirror]  Nope.

Answer (score 2):

## No, there is no shame in that.

> On one hand, it feels funny to have (e.g.) the opening sentence be the same, and if the reviewers notice it, it might look unprofessional.

I usually try to have the "opening sentence" be different, but that is really more a matter of personal preference than anything else. I don't find it "unprofessional" if I review grant proposals where the main proposal and the abstract start with the same sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine. Grant reviewers are used to seeing similar (or the same) information listed in different parts of a grant. It also helps you keep your message consistent.